# how does angular search for variable through its $scope chain

Tags: javascript, angularjs, optimization, scope

```
(function(){
  var outer = 'foo';
  (function(){
    var inner = 'bar';
    return [inner, outer];
  })();
})();
```

the above code creates a slow resolution as the inner function #outer will need to check the nearest object first and see that it doesn't contain 'outer' and then look for the variable in the next level of scope chain.

Does the following angular code behave the exact same way? If so then should we beware of scope creation and scope chain variable finding?

```
angular.module('app', [], function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.rootVar = 'root Variable';
})
.controller('ctrl1', function($scope){
    $scope.var1 = rootVar;
})
.controller('ctrl2', function($scope){ //nested
    $scope.var2 = rootVar;
})
```

Comment: In your example rootVar should not be available as a standalone variable, only as a property on $scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angular you're not creating inner scopes in the same way, you're passing a variable that contains the "scope".  So you can't just reference rootVar, it doesn't exist in the current functions scope, except as a property on `$scope` which you passed in.  So you need to change your references to

```
angular.module('app', [], function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.rootVar = 'root Variable';
})
.controller('ctrl1', function($scope){
    $scope.var1 = $scope.rootVar;
})
.controller('ctrl2', function($scope){ //nested
    $scope.var2 = $scope.rootVar;
})
```

Comment: right, typo, but do you know how the search iterator begins? hwo bad the performance would be?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking.  These calls won't iterate. They look for a variable named $scope.  They find one right there in the local scope, and at that point will stop looking.  They will read the property rootVar off of it.  There will be no performance impact.

Comment: no, if they are not in local scope, they elevate the scope and try to look into $scope.$parent.rootVar, and if that still doesn't return a match, it looks for $scope.$parent.$parent, eventually you get to $rootScope, which returns nothing, then it will set it to undefined. so during this process, is there a lot of performance hit?

Comment: No what it does is look at the current $scope's prototype.  If it isn't on the object or its prototype chain, then it doesn't exist.  There is not a significant performance hit to look up a prototype chain.

Comment: thanks,so the prototype of a $scope points to its $parent attribute as a reference.